# Suggestion to start a Stack site for providing help regarding psychological issues

Tags: feature-request

I didn't find any Stack site related to helping people (this includes IT/developer guys as well) deal with various psychological issues. So, can we have a Stack site related to psychological issues only?

This site can work like pretty much most other Stack sites - people will come here and tell about a specific problem they're dealing with and describe what measures they've already taken to solve it, and whether there's any better way of solving it. Also, if possible, some level of psychological support can be provided to people in order to help them overcome the problem on their own, rather than taking medicines.

We sometimes tell people that they should talk to somebody when they face a serious problem in life and can't figure out themselves what to do. So this Stack site on Psychological help can be that place where people can find someone they can talk to.

It is important for IT/developer people as well, because psychological issues affect their productivity in the workplace greatly.

Comment: [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @bluefeet Ok, good. I didn't know about that before. It's very kind of you to point this out to me.

Comment: See: [How can I propose a new site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/262755). Also, [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/262755)

Comment: Awesome bad idea.

Comment: This would be horrible in so many ways.

Comment: Ok ... ... how's it a bad idea? Care to explain???

Comment: @Capt.JackSparrow Bill the Lizard's answer explains, generally. You don't want psychological advice from random people on the Internet. They don't know you or your situation well enough, aren't able to get the information they need, and won't be qualified.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks for clearing, mate. :)

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if a Q&A site is the best place to seek help with psychological issues. People would most often be much better off seeking advice from a close friend, family member, or trained professional. The kind of posts you find on Stack Exchange sites normally consist of a question and one or two answers, and hopefully one of the answers is definitive. Helping people with psychological issues doesn't really fit that mold. I think it would normally take a back-and-forth conversation, which the main SE sites are not really set up to support.

Comment: **"I don't know if a Q&A site is the best place to seek help with..."** You're being polite, I know. I would say it's close to the worst place to do so.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Close, but reddit would be closer. =D

Comment: @J.Steen And 4chan even closer. I'd expect the response there to be brutal.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @AndrewBarber. I think [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27065887/1288) was experiencing "pychological" issues earlier.

Comment: I need some binary suppositories, myself. Not sure how that revelation relates to anything, though!